# drop_objection fails to drop objection

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have simple main_phase as:

```
virtual task main_phase(uvm_phase phase);
 super.main_phase(phase);
 phase.raise_objection( this );
 #2us;
 phase.drop_objection( this );
endtask : main_phase
```

This test will timeout, but if i comment out raise_objection and drop_objection test will finish properly, with out executing #2us obviously.

Based on debugging it seems that drop_objection do not trigger m_events[].all_dropped which require for phase to complete.
Reason is in side m_evens uvm_root object but drop_objection trys for test object, so it miss-matched.

Any suggestion what may be wrong?
I am using UVM-1.2
Thanks,

Comment: You need to construct an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I added your code to a simple testbench of mine and it worked fine - the test stopped at 2us.

Comment: You can use `phase.phase_done.display_objections();` to see if you have any outstanding objections that were raised but not dropped.

Comment: What if you comment out only `raise_objection`?

Comment: Add `+UVM_OBJECTION_TRACE` as a runtime argument to your simulation

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for suggestion.
Here is what turns to be a problem. Recently some one added to base test drain time. My test very short one so i added short time out at command line. I wish that generated error was more descriptive. I found this by running small test and in UVM phase execution last thing was drain time as expected.
Albert,